# Can not download 6 months TSLA with interval of 1 minute in yfinance

Tags: python, yfinance

I want to download 6 month data of TSLA with resolution of 1 minute, but the code returned an empty dataframe.

`symbol_history = yf.Ticker('TSLA').history(period='1d', interval='1m') # OK`

`symbol_history = yf.Ticker('TSLA').history(period='max', interval='1m') # OK with 6 days period`

`symbol_history = yf.Ticker('TSLA').history(period='6mo', interval='1m') # Not OK. Empty Dataframe`

Is there any limitation of pair of periods and intervals?

How to get these data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the yfinance [Wiki](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/wiki/Ticker)

> Intraday data cannot extend last 60 days
>
> - 1m - max 7 days within last 30 days
> - up to 90m - max 60 days
> - 60m, 1h - max 730 days (yes 1h is technically < 90m but this what Yahoo does)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As the second part of my question I found out I can break the longer periods to shorter periods that can be processed by yfinance.

Comment: Oh, that's neat. I've tried that and it didn't work but that was a long time ago, maybe they've updated their API. :^)